# Couldn't read the contents of a file from UNNotificationServiceExtension class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I have a `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class and from `didReceive` delegate method I want to read user information from .dat file.

```
var value : String? = nil

//filePath has valid path with filename

if(filepath != nil){
     value = try? String(contentsOfFile: filepath!)
}
```

When I print the value it is nil.
I even tried to write the value that I need into `UserDefaults` from the app and tried to read the value from `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class but it is still nil. I am even unable to read the value from keychain from `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class.

Any other inputs are appreciated.

Expected result is I should be able to read a file content or read a value from UserDefaults/Keychain in `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class.

Comment: Use `try` instead of `try?` with `do {} catch {}` to see if it throws an error.

Comment: The extension means is app, see Apple’s recommendations on the developer’s portal. You should create app groups to access.